# Error mounting/format/part bootable USB

Tags: partitioning, mount, format, usb-drive

```
Error mounting: mount: block device /dev/sde2 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so


dmesg |tail output:
[35386.452383] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_entry_txstatus_timeout: Warning - TX status timeout for entry 6 in queue 0
[35386.452401] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_entry_txstatus_timeout: Warning - TX status timeout for entry 6 in queue 0
[35386.452404] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_entry_txstatus_timeout: Warning - TX status timeout for entry 6 in queue 0
[36189.980082] isofs_fill_super: bread failed, dev=sde1, iso_blknum=16, block=32
[37247.825497] hfsplus: invalid secondary volume header
[37247.825501] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[37542.436324] hfsplus: invalid secondary volume header
[37542.436328] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[38649.462360] hfsplus: invalid secondary volume header
[38649.462365] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

Otherwise I usually get read-only errors etc.

Any way of formatting/erasing this?

I'm trying to make a bootable disk for Mac OSX, but somewhere along the way something is corrupted. I've tried programs and admin settings in Mac OSX (terminal and disk util) and similar things and programs in windows (partition manager, hp usb etc.). I've also tried the standard f-disk and such.

I cant seem to open the graphical user interface for gparted either, even though it is installed. Any way of just wiping the whole disk clean?

Any -su options or otherwise would be great. Thanks!

EDIT: after 3 days and countless efforts i found the simple solution. i simply used:

sudo nautilus
exited the nautilus 
opened disk utility and i have no problems wiping the USB.

However, windows still recalls this is a RAW, mac osx can't boot since file system almost got to fat32(but corrupted) error in diskutility: error: creating partition table: helper exited with exit code 1: cannot open /dev/sdd: Read-only file system

tried sudo chmod in all variations, still no access...i feel like im soo close...

Answer (score 0):

If you have ever had an isohybrid image on that usb, you could have a leftover "iso9660 filesystem".  Since that filesystem is in the first 64 sectors of the disk, you can't delete it by deleting partitions.
I have always been successful in repairing uncooperative usb drives with the dd command. It will wipe the whole drive, so be double-d sure that you enter the command correctly, for the correct drive. Run the command sudo parted -l first to check the correct device.
Use this command to wipe the drive.
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512
  - where sdX is your usb drive, in this case, sde

It will take about 20 minutes to complete an 8 GB usb drive, so be patient.     After that you can create partitions and format them.